# replace unknown line in file linux command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to change a line with a pattern in a textual file using Linux bash. 
I tried the sed command:

```
sed -i 's/old/new/' < file.txt
```

The issue with this command line I have to specify the exact "old" word. I want to change thousands of files where the old word has a pattern like this: old1(, old2(,old3(,....old10000(
I would like to change the oldxxx( in all files to old1( 
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: So the thing that you want to change is "old" followed by some digits? What would you like to change it to?

Comment: I want to always change oldxx( to old1(

Comment: @KJohn You should update your question to include some sample patterns and what should be the expected output from it. That would help in getting better and more clear answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
sed -i 's/old[0-9]\{1,\}(/old1(/' file.txt
```

This matches "old" followed by one or more digits and a "(" and replaces it with "old1(".

If your version of sed supports extended regular expressions, you can use:

```
sed -r -i 's/old[0-9]+\(/old1(/' file.txt
```

instead, which does the same thing. On some versions of sed, the `-E` switch is used instead of `-r`.

If you have more than one instance of the pattern "oldXX(" on the same line, you may also want to the `g` modifier (`s/.../.../g`) to do a global replacement.